# JdbcTemplate query() giving empty ResultSet when it shouldn't

Tags: java, hsqldb, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am writing unit tests for some legacy code.  I have a method like this

```
public Map<String, List<NotificationKeyBasic>> getDueBusinessCaseList(int numberOfDays) {
        String sql = "select bh.hotelid from dbo.BUSCASEHOTELMASTER bh\n" +
                "where (select  bh.closedate - trunc(sysdate) diff from dual) = ?\n";
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ResultSetExtractor<Map<String, List<NotificationKeyBasic>>>() {
            @Override
            public Map<String, List<NotificationKeyBasic>> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                Map<String, List<NotificationKeyBasic>> mapStringKey = new HashMap<String, List<NotificationKeyBasic>>();
                List<NotificationKeyBasic> notificationKeys;

                while (rs.next()) {
                    //do stuff here
                }
                return mapStringKey;
            }
        }, numberOfDays);
    }
}
```

The ResultSet is empty when this method runs.  We are using an in memory HSQL database for testing purposes.  I have an xml dataset file with this in it

```
<dataset>
  <dbo.buscasehotelmaster closedate="2012-04-04" hotelid="44" />
</dataset>
```

All the test code works properly like it should.  The problem I am having is that when I pass in `numberOfDays`, as parameter for `query()`, the ResultSet is empty.  However, when I hard code the difference between the two dates as -1007, (trunc(sysdate) is 1/6/2015 as of today so the difference between the two dates is -1007) it works and ResultSet is not empty.  I am not sure why this is happening, and changing the existing code is not an option.  Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What values have you used for "numberOfDays"?

Comment: I have used -1006, -1007, and -1008

Comment: And "where (select  bh.closedate - trunc(sysdate) diff from dual) = -1007\n"; actually works when you set the value directly?

Comment: Yes, hard coding -1007 works.